# Xcode failed to log metrics boringssl

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xcode, boringssl

I'm building a simple Xcode project to help me calculate taxes. I'm requesting an xml url but getting the error:

> [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics

I've rode that the error can disappear if you test it on a real device, but I've still got the error.

```
import UIKit

    class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var model: DetailModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadSteuer()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func loadSteuer(){
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.bmf-steuerrechner.de/interface/2022Version1.xhtml")!
        guard var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false )else {
            return
        }
        
        let queryItemCode = URLQueryItem(name: "code", value: "Lohn2022")
        let queryItemLzz = URLQueryItem(name: "LZZ", value: "1")
        let queryItemRe4 = URLQueryItem(name: "Re4", value: model?.bruttolohnCents)
        let queryItemStk1 = URLQueryItem(name: "STKL", value: model?.steuerklasseString)
        let queryItemAJahr = URLQueryItem(name: "AJAHR", value: model?.alterString)
        components.queryItems = [queryItemCode, queryItemLzz, queryItemRe4, queryItemStk1, queryItemAJahr]
        
        guard let queryURL = components.url else {
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: queryURL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
            
        }.resume()
    }
    }

    extension DetailViewController: XMLParserDelegate {
    
     func parser(_ parser: XMLParser,
                didStartElement elementName: String,
                namespaceURI: String?,
                qualifiedName qName: String?,
                attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        switch elementName {
        case "ausgabe":
            
            if attributeDict["name"] == "LSTLZZ"{
                print(attributeDict["value"])
            }
            
            if attributeDict["name"] == "SOLZLZZ"{
                print(attributeDict["value"])            }
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no explanation but found [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/79025) on apple site

Comment: Also found [this other one](https://mastodon.social/@bigzaphod/100584495206745949)

Comment: @PtitXav yes i saw this solution already but it doesnt fix the problem its just disabling the appearing in the console and other important errors. so thats not a good solution cause im losing important information but the code still not work :/

Comment: Was is the xml format of element ausgabe ? Something like  <ausgabe name="nnnn" value="vvv" >….

Comment: Firebase needs to answer this question; it's embarrassing their software causes ugly complaints in the console for programs which are running well.